# Flash does not respect the arguments passed accents in grails

Tags: grails

I'm new to grails, the problem arises when notified about a change and registration database has an accent, does not show it correctly.

**Controller code:**

```
flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'GiroComercial.label', default: 'GiroComercial'), giroComercialInstance.giroComercial])
```

**Messages properties code:**

```
default.updated.message={0} {1} Actualizado
```

**Results:**

[image: photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have html entities in your messages, you'll need

```
${raw(flash.message)}
```

In your gsp

Be careful though, if you're displaying user input in your messages, as this might expose you to injection

Comment: Thank you very much It works. 
I have in mind what you comment me thanks

Comment: Cool :-)  If you tick the checkbox on the left of my answer, you can accept it :-)  Thanks!  And good luck!